# Why rails use redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rails-activestorage

I am trying to develop a small rails application. I previously used CarriereWave to store files, but just change to use ActiveStorage. When I save a new record (or destroy a record) , application crash with error message:

```rb
Disk Storage (1.4ms) Uploaded file to key: yltgtiwm190dz7kemaj8plz6acpq (checksum: Xjy3wdZBK+KWDKkEgTPVmw==)
[ActiveJob] Failed enqueuing ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob to Sidekiq(default): Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED))
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 373ms (ActiveRecord: 310.0ms | Allocations: 18043)

Redis::CannotConnectError (Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)):
```

However, record is perfectly recorded.

When I start a Redis server, everything work fine, but my question is:

Why does my rails application use Redis, and is it possible to disable it ? (As I use google app engine for production, I do not want to setup Redis server on it).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Doop! Yup. Oh ActiveStorage...

Answer (score 1):

Search into *config/environments/** for some code related (Cache or whatever)

This is a example for Redis as cache in my config/environments/production.rb

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: "redis://<my_server>:6379/0" }
end
```

Search to into *config/initializers/redis.rb*

Redis is not mandatory. You have some code to activate it.

Sugestion:

```sh
$ cd my_app
$ grep -i redis * -r
```

Comment: In this case, redis is required by sidekiq, not cache store

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is there a way to disable using redis with sidekiq (or disable sidekiq when using ActiveStorage) ?